# Several problems with slideshow using text instead of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I used a image slideshow to create a text slideshow. I need help with several things. I'm still learning coding so it has been a little complicated.

I am not able to make it responsive?? Whenever I tried to make my window smaller, or look into it in mobile, I think is my padding what makes my divs width really small and it looks bad. There's also a horizontal scrolling going on and Im not sure how to fix it.

Also, when making the window smaller, I would like my arrows to go below the text and not over the text.

Can someone help me with this? I would be truly thankful!

Here's the codepen:

http://codepen.io/tsalgadoromero/pen/jBgqmY

```js
var slideIndex = 1;showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} ;   
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.w3-content {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: auto;
}

.w3-center {
  text-align: center!important
}

.w3-display-container {
  position: relative
}

.w3-black {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #000!important
}

.w3-display-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-0%, -50%)
}

.w3-display-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%)
}

.w3-button {
  white-space: normal;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.w3-button:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ccc!important;
}

.mySlides {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  text-indent: 50px;
}

.w3-content {
  text-indent: 50px;
  font-family: droid serif;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="w3-center">Title </h1>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <p>

    <div class="mySlides">

      <i style="font-family: open sans; font-size: 18px; letter-spacing: 1.5px; display: block; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center;"> Subtitle </i><br>
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

        <p>
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>


    <!------ Section 2 ------>

    <div class="mySlides"> " In reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."


    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">bleh bleh333</div>

    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I saw was with the navigation arrows...
So the only thing I changed is the `left` and `right` position of these absolute positioned arrows.

The forked [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/full/ryXLNX/) in full page mode.

```
.w3-display-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(16px + 1em);            /* button padding 1 one character */
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-0%, -50%)
}

.w3-display-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: calc(16px + 1em);            /* button padding 1 one character */
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%)
}
```